# jqGrid TreeGrid not send additional data to server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

I have a jqGrid Treegrid defined as below:

```
$('#MyGrid').jqGrid({
    colNames: ['Id','Nome','Nivel','Combo',''],
    colModel: [
        { hidden: true, name: 'Id' },
        { editable: true, name: 'Nome' },
        { hidden: true, name: 'Nivel' },
        { name: 'Combo', editable: true, edittype: 'select',
            editoptions: {
                buildSelect: createSelectList ,
                dataUrl: '/Home/GetCombo' // <-- to this controller, I want
                    // to send the id of the row edited to load custom items
                    // in select object
            }}, 
        { formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true },
            resizable: false, search: false, sortable: false,
            width: 60, viewable: false, name: 'actions' }
    ],
    cellEdit: true,
    url: '...',
    datatype: 'json',
    editurl: '...',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: 'Id',
        subgrid: { repeatitems: false }
    }, 
    mtype: 'POST',
    gridComplete: function() { myOnGridComplete(); },
    ajaxSelectOptions: {
        data: {
            tempid: function () {
                // !!! the next line always returns null
                return $('#MyGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            }
        }
    }, 
    prmNames: { npage: 'npage' }, 
    rowNum: -1,
    ExpandColClick: true,
    ExpandColumn: 'Nome',
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    width: 700,
    height: '100%'
});
```

My goal is to send the current row ID to the server, but when I use *$('#MyGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')* I always get a null value.

I already read this posts but none of them solve my problem:

- [having trouble with jqgrid dataUrl function code segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148843/having-trouble-with-jqgrid-dataurl-function-code-segment/8150307#8150307)
- [jqGrid setSelect function with parametrized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063876/jqgrid-setselect-function-with-parametrized-query/8067258#8067258)
- [jqGrid, how to populate select list from query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841739/jqgrid-how-to-populate-select-list-from-query)

Any sugestions?

tks in advance!

**Update 1:**

The TreeGrid bind is ok. The real problem is when I click the Edit Button in the leaf node. In this event, I want to send additional data to the server.

I tried to accomplish this using the `ajaxSelectOptions`, but this command always returns null: `$('#MyGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow')`

**Workaround**

This is a workaround that I did before Oleg's help:

Step 1: Create a hidden field in the HTML

Step 2: In my myOnGridComplete function, I set a click event to the edit button:

```
function onGridAjusteDTOComplete()
{
    $('#MyGrid').find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            var rowID = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
            // !!! the next commented line not work in my case
            // $('#MyGrid').jqGrid('setSelection', therowid );
            $('#myHiddenField').val(rowID); // <-- this works
        });
    });
}
```

Step 3: Get the `rowID` from the hidden field in the `ajaxSelectOptions`:

```
ajaxSelectOptions: "{type: 'GET', contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',dataType: 'json',cache: false, async:false, data: {id: function () { return $('#myHiddenField').val(); }}}"
```

**Solution**

See the solution provided by Oleg below. It's just amazing. Thank you Oleg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your problem correctly. TreeGrid send **automatically** the id of parent node during loading of children nodes. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadjacency_model#what_we_post) about `nodeid`, `parentid`, `n_level` parameters which will be send to the server. So I don't understand why you could need to send the id of the currently selected row (`selrow`) additionally to the server.

**UPDATED**: Now I understand the reason of the problem which you describe. It's really interesting problem which could have other people.

The real solution would be to change the code of jqGrid to support some callback function which could construct the `data` parameter used in `$.ajax` call which build `<select>`. The simplest modification of the original code of jqGrid will be to insert the line

```
var rowid = $.jgrid.stripPref($t.p.idPrefix,
        String(options.id).substring(0, String(options.id).length - String(options.name).length - 1));
```

before [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.common.js#L346) line of code where `$.ajax` with `dataUrl` will be called. Additionally one need to add one more parameter in the `$.ajax`:

```
data: $.isFunction(ajaxso.postData) ?
    ajaxso.postData.call($t, rowid, String(options.name), vl) :
    ajaxso.postData,
```

After such changes one will be able to use

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    postData: function (rowid, colName, value) {
        return { id: rowid };
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectIdForActions_.htm) demonstrate that the approach work. You could see in Fiddler, Firebug or in Developer Tools that the option `id` will be really send to the URL. I'll post the corresponding suggestion to trirand later (I want to make some additional improvements for more common case)

If you need to implement the solution with the current version of jqGrid you can do the following instead. You can "subclass" the method `$.jgrid.createEl` which do the `$.ajax` request. The implementation will also simple enough:

```
var originalCreateEl = $.jgrid.createEl,
    createElementOptions;

$.extend($.jgrid, {
    createEl: function (eltype, options, vl, autowidth, ajaxso) {
        if (options.dataUrl) {
            createElementOptions = options;
        }
        return originalCreateEl.call(this,eltype, ptions,vl,autowidth,ajaxso);
    }
});

$('#MyGrid').jqGrid({
    ...
    ajaxSelectOptions: {
        data: {
            id: function () {
                var id = createElementOptions.id,
                    colName = createElementOptions.name;
                if (typeof id !== "string" || typeof colName !== "string") {
                    return null;
                }
                return id.substring(0, id.length - colName.length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[The next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SelectIdForActions.htm) demonstrate the way.

**UPDATED 2**: I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/404) to make support of `postData` as property of `` ` and ``ajaxSelectOptions`. The request is committed now (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/c5a4998582cbf60761ab8d7c96f36b784a51857b)). So the next version of jqGrid (higher as 4.4.1) will have the functionality "out of the box".

Comment: Hi Oleg. Tnks for the help. My problem is not to bind the treegrid. this is working ok. My problem is when I click on the Edit button in the leaf node. In this click event, I wanto to send additional data to the server. With this additional info, I can, for example, bind diffenrent information for each combobox in diffenrent row.

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: Is the editing row is really selected in your scenario? `selrow` equal to `null` mean that no row is selected. The `formatter: 'actions'` don't prevent selection of rows. Probably the code which you use in `myOnGridComplete` prevent in some way the selection of row during editing?

Comment: Hi Oleg. I've found the solution. In myOnGridComplete I set a click event to the Edit and get the row id into a Hidden Field. After, in the ajaxSelectOptions I pass this id to the server.

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: Sorry, but I don't understand why you need to do this. Binding `click` event handler to every row just get unnecessary memory resources. You don's answered on my question: "Is the editing row is really selected in your scenario?". If you need to trace the last editing row by action formatter you can use `onEdit` callback (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5204793/315935) for example). In any way the it's unclear **why** `selrow` is null. It should be null only if no row is selected.

Comment: Hi Oleg. I'll try with onEdit. Since I get the test, I'll post the results. Tnks.

Comment: I did the tests and noticed that the call to the URL in the parameter dataUrl happens before the event onEdit. I need to get the rowid before the call to dataURL.

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: Now I understand the reason of the problem which you have. The row will be selected, but it will be selected **after** the Ajax request with `ajaxSelectOptions` will be sent. The solution which you suggest is a workaround, but it do too many unneeded work. Especially binding of `click` handler to *every button* seems to me too expensive. The usage of hidden DOM elements is also not needed. Much more easy to declare variable in outer scope. Inside of `beforeSelectRow` callback you can save the id of rows in the variable which you can use inside of `ajaxSelectOptions`.

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: I will append my answer with the corresponding code fragment.

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: I updated my answer. The way with `beforeSelectRow` also don't work because it will be called too late. By the way one more disadvantage of the solution which you described is *the order* of called `click` handles. If the `click` handler of "actions" formatter would be called before youth then you would set the value for `$('#myHiddenField')` too late.

Comment: You're a genius!!! It worked perfectly. It's interesting how this feature did not exist before in jqGrid. Your solution is very simple and clean. Thank you!

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: You are welcome! I will prepare my suggestions and will post there to trirand. I think it could interesting for many other users of jqGrid. What I want to add to the suggestions described in my answer is the possibility to define `postData` callback inside of `editoptions` or `searchoptions`. In the way one will don't need to have one *common* `ajaxSelectOptions.postData` for all columns of jqGrid. I think it would be easier for the usage.

Comment: @WashingtonMorais: I want only inform you (see "**UPDATED 2**" part of my answer) that the corresponding changes in the main code of jqGrid is now on github.